# Convert string into key-value pair array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am reading checkbox name and value. If there are two checkboxes if part gets executed, if single checkboox then else block will get execute.

```
if (Array.isArray(b.name)) {
  b.options = b.name.map(function(v, i) {
    return [v, b.value[i]];
  });
} else {
  b.options = b.name.map(function(v, i) {
    return [v, b.value[i]];
  });
}
```

For example:
[image]

In the above code if block will get executed only when there are multiple value and it works fine because we have an Array.

`name = Spine` and `value = Spine Value`
But in below scenario:

[image]

Here else part will get execute from the above snippet. But here it is returning an error saying that `b.name.map is not a function`.

How do I convert this string into an array similar to if block.

Tried approached so far in else block:

```
b.options = $.each(function(v, i) {
  return [b.name, b.value];
});
```

```
$.each({name: b.name, value: b.value}, function(k, v) {
  b.options = (k + "" + v);
});
```

Comment: Error is correct, `String` doesn't have `.map()` method. You need to handle `else` section of `if` block. Better See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I tried converting this sting value into key value pair but not working. Let me update the question with tried approached in else block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine both cases by concatenating your `b.name` value with an empty array:

```
b.options = [].concat(b.name).map(function(v,i) { 
    return [v, b.value[i]]; 
});
```

in that way, you will get an array from `b.name` when is a string and also when it is an array already. You may need to handle the case when `b` or `b.name` is `undefined` though. Or you can use more general zip function:

```
var zip = function(arr1, arr2) {
  var a = [].concat(arr1);
  var b = [].concat(arr2);
  var len = Math.min(a.length, b.length)

  return a.slice(0, len).map(function(item, i){
      return [a[i], b[i]];
  });
}

b.options = zip(b.name, b.value);
```

Mind in that case that the returned array will have the length of the shortest array.

Comment: This works perfect but when I enter name as MONDAY and value as START_WEEK ...it IS displaying MONDAY as name correctly but attribute value="s" instead of value="START_WEEK".

Comment: I guess this is happening because in that case, b.value is a string. You can use the same trick with the empty array on b.value, or better use some more general 'zip' funcition like the one in my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

if b.name has length attribute,you can use 'call'

```
if(Array.isArray(b.name)){
   b.options = Array.prototype.map.call(b.name,function(v,i) { 
            return [v, b.value[i]]; 
   })
}else{
   b.options = Array.prototype.map.call(b.name,function(v,i) { 
            return [v, b.value[i]]; 
   })
}
```

Comment: if block is perfect for multiple name values but single name and value it is returning below error jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in Spine

Comment: If I enter name as MONDAY it is adding M as checkbox , O as checkbox and so on instead MONDAY as checkbox